# How can I pass a function multiplied by a constant as argument in Python

Tags: python, functional-programming, arguments

How can I pass a function multiplied by a constant as argument? This is for sake of modularity of my code. If I do

```
def foo(fcn, **kwargs):
    return fcn(2, **kwargs["param1"])

def fcn1(x, **kwargs):
    return x ** kwargs["power"]

foo(4 * fcn1)
```

this will give error `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'float' and 'function'`
.

I don't want this constant to be in foo, since it's not really a part of foo's functionality. Lmabda expression is a way but doesn't look nice such as `foo(lambda x: 4 * fcn1)`

Comment: `def foo(fcn, const): return const * fcn(2)` ?

Comment: I don't want this constant to be in foo, since it's not really a part of foo's functionality. Lmabda expression is a way but doesn't look nice.

Comment: Python functions don't represent mathematical functions. They represent instructions for doing things. For Python functions, supporting the `*` operator would be more confusing than useful.

Comment: You should share your real code

Answer (score 2):

Use a lambda to define an anonymous function inline:

```
foo(lambda x: 4 * fcn1(x))
```

You could hide this behind a helper function:

```
def times_n(n, f):
    return lambda x: n * f(x)

foo(times_n(4, fcn1))
```

If you don't like lambdas you can use all named functions:

```
def times_n(n, f):
    def fn(x):
        return n * f(x)
    return fn
```

A new `fn(x)` will be created each time `times_n()` is called, bound to varying values of `n`.

Answer (score 0):

You could always do something like

```
def foo(fcn, const=1):
    return const*fcn(2)
foo(fcn1, 4)
```

In other words, just use an optional parameter.

Comment: I don't want this constant to be in foo, since it's not really a part of foo's functionality.